# Is there a way to push updates to deployed android things board

Tags: iot, android-things

I'm looking to start an internet of things project. I really like android things as a development environment, but there is one glaring problem. There seems to be no way to update an android things project after it has been deployed. My question is can you push updates to your IOT devices using android things? If not is there something like android things that has updating as a feature?

Comment: FYI this is not a duplicate. This question is about updating _your_ android app, and the "original dupe" is about updating the android operating system.

Comment: But I still have the feeling that your question is too broad. In essence, you are asking: is there some external tool that does xyz. And such questions are especially off-topic here as well. Maybe https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a better place to ask a *specif* clear question.